# Carry symbols using xlop

Tags: xlop

Is there a way to achieve the same type of carry symbols like the addition and subtraction examples when using opmul?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{pstricks}

     \begin{document}


     \section{Arithmetic}

                    \subsection{Addition}
                
\opadd[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\white]{356}{278}
\opadd[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\blue]{356}{278}
\opadd[carryadd=true, resultstyle=\blue, carrystyle=\scriptsize\red]{356}{278}
                
                \subsection{Subtraction}
            
\opsub[carrysub=false, resultstyle=\white]{482}{299}
\opsub[carrysub=false, resultstyle=\blue]{482}{299}
\opsub[carrysub=true, resultstyle=\blue, carrystyle=\scriptsize\red]{482}{299}              
            
                \subsection{Multipication}
            
\opmul[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\white]{215}{36}
\opmul[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\blue]{215}{36}
\opmul[carryadd=true, resultstyle=\blue, carrystyle=\scriptsize\red]{215}{36}           
            
                \subsection{division}
            
\opdiv[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\white]{213}{3}
\opdiv[carryadd=false, resultstyle=\blue]{213}{3}
\opdiv[carryadd=true, resultstyle=\blue, carrystyle=\scriptsize\red]{213}{3}    

\end{document}
```

I know the code still says carryadd=true but I cant it to carrymul its will not render. So is there a work around?

Comment: It's a bit late but there's a workaround: you can use \oplput(-2,2){\scriptsize$2$} 
Change the position (-2,2) and the carry number accordingly. I hope this helps